# Installed Django with PIP, django.admin.py returns command not found. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: macos, bash, pip, django-1.5

I installed django 1.5.1 with PIP.

I am trying to learn Django, and tried to make a test project.

When I run `pip freeze`, it returns `Django==1.5.1` as one of my installed packages.

When I run `django-admin.py startproject test_project` it returns, `-bash: django-admin.py: command not found`.

I cannot start this test project. Any advice as to how I can start a new django project?

I am on a Mac OSX 10.5.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on [this page.](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/InstallationPitfalls)

I was able to solve my path issue by running:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

This created a "Permission Denied" error though. I was able to solve that issue by running:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

django-admin.py is now working.

Answer (score 2):

I have used follwong command to install (/usr/local/bin)

```
pip install django

django-admin startproject mysite
```